# Mechanisms to prevent developers from spinning up too man or too large of AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a team new to AWS looking to migrate to utilizing AWS cloud over our internal cloud provider.  The powers that be wanted to give dashboard access to a number of developers to support them learning and supporting our development and deployment.  However, they are worried about the costs if someone goes crazy and starts spinning up a large number of huge VM's

I'm aware that AWS has a limit of 20 total VMs in a region by default, but we have already had them raise our limit significantly (somewhere in the 80-90) range to support what I consider to be an overly high estimation of total VMs we will eventually need.  That still leaves room for quite a few expensive VMs to be spun up if a developer goes overboard.

Are there any tools that the owner of an AWS account can use to put some soft upper limits on number of VMs or total cost of VMs that developers with roles thta allow them to create a VM would still be limited by to better restrict this?  For example we are going to start by spinning up a much smaller integration environment before moving on to production, so can we temporarily put limit to prevent someone spinning up 80 vm's until were ready to start implementing a prod environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, remember, on the root account make IAM accounts. You can also make groups and roles.

Roles are mostly reserved for non-human aws functions, so you want to create some groups.

Best practice is to create a dev group and an admins group. Make yourself an admin and give yourself administratorAccess (literally the first choice) and then finish creating the group. Put your IAM account in that.

Then put all the dev's into other IAM groups. The best way to stop a dev from spinning up too many instances is to not give them that power. Only let you spin up, or a trusted dev spin it up.

There is no "20 count limit" that you can impose on devs that I am aware of. You either have permission to spin up new ones or you don't.

I personally wouldn't worry too much about it because any ec2's that they spin up, you would be able to see too. You can just shut them down if someone opens up 20 in 5 minutes.

If someone was pissed at you and wanted to quit.... they could try to mess with you but you have bigger problems then.

Just have a clear corporate policy that we try not to spin up too many instances unless necessary. And also have a policy where you take AMI's and snapshots and give people the ability to stop ec2 instances if they are working on it.